# Why I can't shrink the width image when I reduce the browser window?

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

1 Why I can't shrink the width image when I reduce the browser window ?

2 Why the image not in the center red div ?

in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/2uR3h/10/) I can shrink the image (browser chrome).

[image]

in my [site](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/responsive_image.html) I can't shrink the image (browser chrome).

[image]

the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style type='text/css'>
    #Blue
{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
margin:0px auto;
height: auto;
width: 97%;
z-index: 10;
background:azure;
    border:5px solid blue;

}
#Red{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    border:5px solid red;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    bottom:0;

}

#Menu{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:yellow;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
}

img {
    top:0px;      
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;

}
#green{}

@media (max-width: 200px) {

#Menu{
        display:inline;
        margin:1px;
        text-align:center;    
        position:static;
        width:100%;;
    }
#Menu, #Red{
    width:auto!important;
    height:auto!important;
}

 #Red, img{
    position:static;
    max-width:100%;
}
}    

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Blue">
<div id="Menu">Menu</div>   
    <div id="Red">

        <div id="Green">
            <picture alt="description of image">

  <img src="http://www.candcsavannahs.com/images/queenpawnee2.jpg" alt="description of image">

</picture>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The browser window has a minimum size, meaning you can't make it any smaller. In the fiddle, the image shrinks because it's constrained to a much smaller portion of the window. Use a bigger image on your site to see the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the Picture tag? It's not a standard html tag and removing it seem to make it work.

```
        <div id="Green">
            <!-- <picture alt="description of image"> -->

  <img src="http://www.candcsavannahs.com/images/queenpawnee2.jpg" alt="description of image">

<!--    </picture> -->
        </div>
```

Comment: it is not help me you can see it here http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/responsive_image.html

Comment: @Sparky672 AFAIK html5 is still in draft? but ok, I'm not gonna split hairs

Comment: I'm not saying you should use it.  You asked, _"What is the Picture tag?"_ and I simply provided you an answer.